# How to format Pen Drive on Mac OS X programmatically?

Tags: macos, cocoa, usb-drive

How can I format a pen drive programmatically with particular disc type like fat, exFat, NTFS etc. I am trying in cocoa, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its with NSTask.

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/env"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"diskutil", @"eraseVolume", @"ms-dos", nmToPD, pathToPD,nil]];

NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NSFileManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html)

```
- (BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

or

You can use `diskutil` command with `eraseDisk` option